# Search different value from a table

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have a table like this

```
id     '    type        '      title <br>
1     ' Signature      '   Sample signature <br>
2     ' Documents      '   Sample documents <br>
3     ' Scholarship    '   Sample scholarship <br>
```

And sql

```
$info = array('Signature','Documents');
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_docs WHERE type='$info'";
```

But why does the signature and documents not showing?

Comment: how you are getting `Signature` and `Documents` values to assign into array `$info`?

Comment: Have you tried to `echo $sql`? Because it will print `SELECT * FROM tbl_docs WHERE type='Array'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate an array to a string, this want work

Example :
http://codepad.org/BDhfzxjj

If you're trying to retrieve the document where type is either equal to Signature or Document the best way to do it is to use the `IN` statement with sql.

One effective way to do it from your array is to use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$info = array('Signature','Documents');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_docs WHERE type in ('".implode('\', \'',$info)."')";
```

Example : http://codepad.org/55Ef9zqr

Sql code in action : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d91d0/1

Comment: There is a message showing this. Unknown column 'Signature' in 'where clause'

Comment: @SchyronSy I forgot the single quote. Edited my post with more example ? Tell me if it works ?

Answer (score 0):

the `SQL WHERE` clause takes expressions of the form `<var> = <value>` where value is atomic. If you need multiple values you can use `<var> IN <value list>`. Your query will work, but if the users can enter the values, there is a SQL injection vulnerability. It is better to have a table that contains the items to match, and then join the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_docs WHERE type in '$info'";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Well the correct way of doing this would be like this..

You have to use the **IN** clause

```
$var=join(',',$info);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_docs WHERE type IN ($var)";
```

Comment: There is a message showing this. Unknown column 'Signature' in 'where clause'